# Why does this SQL query not convert the last two letters to Uppercase?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query;

```
SELECT INITCAP(
         first_name
         || ' '
         || UPPER(
              SUBSTR(Last_Name
                    ,-LENGTH(Last_Name)
                    ,2)
            )
         ) 
FROM employees;
```

And the result is like this;

```
David Au
Hermann Ba
Shelli Ba
Amit Ba
Elizabeth Ba
Sarah Be
David Be
```

Why aren't the last two letters being converted to uppercase? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Because of [INITCAP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions065.htm). Your UPPER function is inside INITCAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying **INITCAP** on the entire resultset, therefore, after the last two characters are converted to UPPER, you are again applying INITCAP. Keep them separate.

```
INITCAP(first_name) || ' ' || UPPER(SUBSTR(Last_Name, -LENGTH(Last_Name),2))
```

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT INITCAP(first_name)
  2    || ' '
  3    || UPPER(SUBSTR(Last_Name, -LENGTH(Last_Name),2))
  4  FROM hr.employees
  5  WHERE rownum <=10;

INITCAP(FIRST_NAME)||''
-----------------------
Ellen AB
Sundar AN
Mozhe AT
David AU
Hermann BA
Shelli BA
Amit BA
Elizabeth BA
Sarah BE
David BE

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: Ah okay, that makes a lot of sense, thank's very much!

Answer (score 1):

Because wrongly placed parentheses -

```
SELECT INITCAP(first_name) || ' ' || UPPER(SUBSTR(Last_Name, -LENGTH(Last_Name),2))
FROM employees;
```